# String: How to replace multiple possible characters with a single character?

Tags: java, string

I would like to replace all `'.'` and `' '` with a `'_'`

but I don't like my code...

is there a more efficient way to do this than:

```
String new_s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll(".","_");
```

?

toLowerCase() just there because I want it lower-cased as well...

Comment: ah my code didn't even work... i guess because it says replaceAll uses regular expressions and so the '.' is a problem

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
String new_s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[ .]", "_");
```

EDIT:

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is using regular expressions, and using `.` inside a character class `[ ]` just recognises a `.` rather than any character.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the replaceAll method receives regular expression as first argument, see documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: how to do this with replace() ?

Answer (score 16):

`s.replaceAll("[\\s\\.]", "_")`

Answer (score 6):

Use `String#replace()` instead of `String#replaceAll()`, you don't need regex for single-character replacement.

I created the following class to test what's faster, give it a try:

```
public class NewClass {

    static String s = "some_string with spaces _and underlines";
    static int nbrTimes = 10000000;

    public static void main(String... args) {

        long start = new Date().getTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTimes; i++)
            doOne();
        System.out.println("using replaceAll() twice: " + (new Date().getTime() - start));



        long start2 = new Date().getTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTimes; i++)
            doTwo();
        System.out.println("using replaceAll() once: " + (new Date().getTime() - start2));

        long start3 = new Date().getTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbrTimes; i++)
            doThree();
        System.out.println("using replace() twice: " + (new Date().getTime() - start3));

    }

    static void doOne() {
        String new_s = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll(".", "_");
    }

    static void doTwo() {
        String new_s2 = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[ .]", "_");
    }

    static void doThree() {
        String new_s3 = s.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_").replace(".", "_");
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

> using replaceAll() twice: 100274
>
> using replaceAll() once: 24814
>
> using replace() twice: 31642

Of course I haven't profiled the app for memory consumption, that might have given very different results.

Comment: would it be more efficient to use replace(' ', '_').replace('.','_') or regex code like beny23 posted?

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use `replace()` because of the objects created and the compilation of the Pattern. But for small `String`s it really doesn't matter that much... only if you plan to use it on a loop or something.

Comment: I did a rough performance test by using both methods 10000 times timing the results were near enough the same (regex was actually a fraction faster).  I guess it'll depend on the size of the string, but if you worry about the difference in performance, the only way is to test it...

Comment: I decided to go with regex because there is some remote (25% chance) possibility in the future I might need to add a 3rd character or something... regex leaves it open for more flexibility. thanks for the performance tests.