# Is there a way to avoid this repetitive method calling?

Tags: java, loops, repeat

I'm using HashMap to count all word instances in an article, I'm trying to remove all non-word characters except spaces(because they're already removed with .split()). Is there a way to not repeat "pWord = pWord.replace(...);" every time and instead loop through and pass different arguments inside parentheses?

```
pWord = pWord.replace('"', '\"');
pWord = pWord.replace("–", "");
pWord = pWord.replace("\"", "");
pWord = pWord.replace(".", "");
pWord = pWord.replace("-", "");
```

Comment: you can try regex

Comment: You have `pWord.replace("–", "");` twice, by the way. And your call to `pWord.replace('"', '\"');` is useless since you're calling `pWord.replace("\"", "");` right after it.

Comment: Sure, there is a way. Just create some collection of symbols you want to replace and go over it in a loop and execute replace with current symbol from this collection.

Comment: I’m no regex expert but something like `pWord = pWord=replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "");`.

Comment: @JacobG.nope thats a - and a _

Comment: Also, you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295621/string-how-to-replace-multiple-possible-characters-with-a-single-character

Comment: @achAmháin i like this one... replace all not lower not upper and not space with empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use `replaceAll` with regex. Here is the sample code with regex for characters that you are replacing in your code:

```
String pWord = "-asdf\\\\adf.asdf\"";
System.out.println(pWord.replaceAll("[(\")(\\\\).-]", ""));
```

Output:

```
asdfadfasdf
```

Also, note [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes)

> The String#replaceAll() interprets the argument as a regular
>   expression. The \ is an escape character in both String and regex. You
>   need to double-escape it for regex

P.S. Useful resource to test your regexes: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you want to remove **ALL NON-LETTER** characters is to re-write the string ignoring all other symbols.

```
String s = "hello world _!@#";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c) || Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isWhitespace(c))
        sb.append(c);
}
s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```